# Import local folder of Golang code

Tags: go

I have an 'example.go' file where I'm trying to import a directory in the same folder.

I have 'example.go' and the 'lucky' dir in the same folder called 'project'.

Here's how I'm trying to import the 'lucky' dir:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    golucky "goLucky"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)
```

But when I run example.go, it looks like it is trying to import it from the go source because it throws the error:

```
    cannot find package "goLucky" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/goLucky (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
```

How can I import the local folder in the same dir as the file?

Comment: @chengbo what if I want to import an online dir. like http://github.com/philipsoutham/golucky/v0.0.1, how can I do that?

Comment: set your `GOPATH`, and then `go get github.com/xxxxx`, `import github.com/xxx/yyy` see http://golang.org/doc/code.html#remote

Comment: @chengbo okay, thank you. How do I set my GOPATH?

Comment: `export GOPATH=/path/to/go`, see http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

Comment: @chengbo Thank you. I made the directory look how it is supposed to. But when I Run $ GoPath = /Projects/dirName/, I get -bash: GOPATH: command not found

Comment: run `export GOPATH=/Projects/dirName/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `GOPATH` [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) and locate your `lucky` dir within that. See http://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization

So for example, if you set `GOPATH=~`, then put your `lucky.go` file in `~/src/lucky/lucky.go` then you should be able to `import "lucky"` successfully.

Comment: what do I type in my .go file to set the GoPath?

Comment: `GOPATH` is an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) and is not set in your .go file, it is set in your shell or system settings.

Comment: Oh, okay. I made the directory look how it is supposed to. But when I Run $ GoPath = /Projects/dirName/, I get -bash: GOPATH: command not found

Comment: Please read the documentation I've already linked. As indicated both in the wikipedia article and the Go documentation, you must run `export GOPATH=...` in order to set its value in bash (other shells may be different).